# Star System Summary Sheets

Tags: science-fiction, tools

I'm updating my Star Wars notes (from hastily scribbled notepads) to a more organised format in a binder and I'd like to make a page that summarises each star-system with helpful information, like habitable planets, notable cities on said planets, type of star, and so on.

**Is there a standard sheet for any gaming system anywhere that I can crib/modify to do this?**

Comment: [This book is amazingly well organized along these lines. Also, it is a hell of a resource for RP](http://www.amazon.com/Essential-Guide-Planets-Moons-Star/dp/0345420683) The one big missing set of stats is population, but this aims to be 'timeless' so population as a fluctuating stat wouldn't fit.

Comment: Have you already looked at [how the Star Wars wiki describe Star systems](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tatoo_system)? If so, could you summarize what you like / don't like with it? Also, are the star-systems you want to organize more custom or cannon?

Comment: Nice book links ~ordering~ However my star systems are custom ones.

Comment: Surely a wiki would be perfect for this as the players could contribute as well...  Plus you can search that easily.

Comment: The wiki would be helpful; but we're changing venues and I'm not going to easily have a pc based source to hand (I find reading wiki's on my phone a bit annoying)

Comment: You could probably create one in Word with very little trouble. That's what I always end up doing for my freeform games, with the caveat that I've moved to Google Docs so I can share with other players.

Comment: If you want something to print out, another source to look at for inspiration on what data to record would be random planet and star system generators.  http://donjon.bin.sh/

Comment: Those random planet generators are great; thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at any exploration-based futuristic game you happen to have copies of, but obviously that's a dead end for you or you wouldn't be asking these questions.

One system that has a good summary for planets or systems is [Stars Without Number](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/86467/Stars-Without-Number%3A-Free-Edition), of which you can get a free pdf download containing useful sector and planet summary sheets near the end. It includes sector maps  if that helps, with the option of adding spacelanes or any other interplanetary content you want. It should be fairly easy to print off a few copies of the sheets. While it may not be perfect, it's better than making your own from scratch.

You may want to remove or replace the 'Tech Level' and 'Tags' boxes which may not be in your game.

Comment: These look much more promising; I was hoping for more answers however, so I'll hold out a bit more!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [how Wookiepedia organizes planetary info](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tatooine) and decide what you want to include or drop out for your notes.

Comment: Very helpful to know what to include; but it's not really suited to printing out...

Comment: I would have made this same exact answer if I didn't read first.

Comment: I own a few sci-fi games, like Traveller, Space Opera etc. Problem is that usually different games put different emphasis on different things (does Star Wars care about actual gravity, for example? In the movies all planets seem to be the same). So you really should decide what you care about, and then design your own.